# Loading jQuery plugin outside yepnope

Tags: jquery, plugins, load, yepnope, script-tag

I'm using yepnope to load jquery, and a bunch of plugins.

I fix the onready "problem" using:

```
var docready=[],$=function(){return{ready:function(fn){docready.push(fn)}}};

yepnope({
  load:["../css/plugins/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"],
  complete: function () {


    $ = jQuery;
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        for(n in docready) docready[n]();
    });

            $(document).ready(function(){ jsLoadingALotofPlugins() });  
  } })
```

But in some pages I **need** to load some plugins normally using script tags:

```
<script src="../css/anotherjQueryPlugin.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

And I get the error:

```
TypeError: $ is undefined
$.fn.player = function(method){...
```

If i use yepnope on load this js i know it will work, but i need to use script tag, 
Is there any workaround to fix this like i did with onready??

Comment: interesting, ive never seen yepnope used that way, typically my usage has been yep : ['thisway.js'],
    nope : ['otherway.js'], complete...

Comment: I dont get the part of "some pages I need to load some plugins normally" can you specify, why? So far I have managed to load all with yepnope except yepnope itself. ;)

Comment: Hi @MaunoV. , Its because its a big site project, and i put yepnope on  the header using usercontrol(include), but some pages already in use are loading the js using script tags and receiving errors, other group of users dont want to learn yepnope nor stop using those tags. I need to make everyone happy.

Comment: Hi @worthycaesar , yepnope for me its just great for loading scripts, its simple and small. I developed a small js who get some patterns in the html and load the specifics plugins for each case, "js on demand"

Comment: Can I ask why you need to use a script tag? Do you not have control over that part of the code? If you can add a script tag, you can add a script to load that external script from within your script tag, and put that in docready?